# Changing centroid marker to font marker using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, symbology, rendering

I'm trying to get a "P" font marker in the middle of my polygon layer.
So far, I've managed to make a simple centroid marker (the basic one) appear on my polygons.

The code doesn't bug, but it doesn't change the simple marker to a font marker.

Here's the code, does anyone know what I am missing?

```py
colorpark = QtGui.QColor(88, 88, 88, 255)
symbo_park = QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayer(color=colorpark, strokeColor=colorpark, strokeWidth=0)
parking_l93.renderer().symbol().changeSymbolLayer(0, symbo_park)
parking_l93.triggerRepaint()

symbol_parkcent = QgsCentroidFillSymbolLayer.create()
parking_l93.renderer().symbol().appendSymbolLayer(symbol_parkcent)
colorP = QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255, 255) 
symbolparkP = QgsFontMarkerSymbolLayer(fontFamily='Arial Black', chr='P', pointSize=2, color=colorP)      
parking_L93.renderer().symbol().changeSymbolLayer(0, symbolparkP)                
parking_l93.triggerRepaint()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `QgsFontMarkerSymbolLayer` must be added as a `subSymbol` to your `QgsCentroidFillSymbolLayer`.

I just needed to add 4 lines to your code to obtain something like this :

[image]

Here is the lines I added :

```
symbol_parkcent = QgsCentroidFillSymbolLayer.create()
# Make the centroid transparent
symbol_parkcent.setColor(QColor("transparent"))
#
colorP = QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255, 255) 
symbolparkP = QgsFontMarkerSymbolLayer(fontFamily='Arial Black', chr='P', pointSize=2, color=colorP)      
# Add the Font Marker as subsymbol
marker_symbol = QgsMarkerSymbol()
marker_symbol.changeSymbolLayer(0, symbolparkP)
symbol_parkcent.setSubSymbol(marker_symbol)
#
parking_l93.renderer().symbol().appendSymbolLayer(symbol_parkcent)
parking_l93.triggerRepaint()
```

By using `appendSymbolLayer` I added your `QgsFontMarkerSymbolLayer` to your `QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayer` If you only want the `QgsFontMarkerSymbolLayer` you need to use `parking_l93.renderer().symbol().changeSymbolLayer(0, symbol_parkcent)`

Comment: Works perfectly, many thanks!